# С++ Как определить собственный метод в таймере?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli, таймер

Код взят отсюда
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

```
private:
   static System::Windows::Forms::Timer^ myTimer = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer;
   static int alarmCounter = 1;
   static bool exitFlag = false;

   // This is the method to run when the timer is raised.
   static void TimerEventProcessor( Object^ /*myObject*/, EventArgs^ /*myEventArgs*/ )
   {
      myTimer->Stop();
      
      // Displays a message box asking whether to continue running the timer.
      if ( MessageBox::Show( "Continue running?", String::Format( "Count is: {0}", alarmCounter ), MessageBoxButtons::YesNo ) == DialogResult::Yes )
      {
         
         // Restarts the timer and increments the counter.
         alarmCounter += 1;
         myTimer->Enabled = true;
      }
      else
      {
         
         // Stops the timer.
         exitFlag = true;
      }
```

Вот к примеру после **myTimer->Stop();**  я хочу использовать собственный метод(функцию), которая выглядит следующим образом :

```
System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw1(){
. . .
}
```

Но выдается следующая ошибка:   E0020   идентификатор "draw1" не определен

Подскажите, как всё таки его определить? Буду благодарен за помощь, так как сильно встрял на этом моменте.

Comment: @AlexF примерно понимаю..но что тогда делать в таком случае?

Comment: @AlexF я в этой функции использую this , так что вряд ли я могу её сделать static. Подождите пожалуйста, лучше и вправду прикреплю код программы к вопросу.

Comment: @AlexF

Если уберу static , выдаст такую ошибку:
E2159 недопустимый инициализатор делегата -- функция не соответствует типу делегата

Comment: Сделайте поиск на "c++ cli timer windows forms example". Эта статья показывает, как работать с таймером в форме: https://mcn-www.jwu.ac.jp/~yokamoto/openwww/vsg/VCpp2012FormApp/GUIComponents/

Comment: @AlexF Хорошо, попробую. Если что, опишусь сюда

Comment: @AlexF Я даже не знаю, как вас благодарить, потому что это единственный рабочий метод из множества тех, которые я перепробовал. Спасибо огромное, вы мне ОЧЕНЬ сильно помогли!